# Mystery Duplications when running an AppScript script for BigQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

The following code should be appending a dataset based on a query to a consolidated table, however it is currently duplicating this data and appending it. I believe this is a regression issue on Google's side. Any help would be more than appreciated!

Thanks - Marc

```
function runQuery1() {
  var configuration = {
     "query": {
     "useQueryCache": false,
     "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": "projectID",
        "datasetId": "datasetID",
       "tableId": "Consolidated"
      },
    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
    "allowLargeResults": true,
    "useLegacySql": false,
     "query": "SELECT cast(PARSE_DATETIME('%e/%m/%E4Y %H:%M',Date) as Date) as Date, Centre FROM Source.Temp",
     }
  };

  var job = {
    "configuration": configuration
   };

  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "projectID");
 Logger.log(jobResult);
  }

runQuery1();
```

Comment: Check your job history with `bq ls -j --all` and see if you find multiple invocations of the query. Use `bq --format=prettyjson show -j <job ID>` to see the query text for a particular job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent duplicated job runs, consider declaring a job id:

```
var configuration = {
  ...
  "jobReference": {
    "jobId": string,
  ...
}
```

From the docs:

> If you use your own job ID, you can check the status of the job at any time, and you can retry on the same job ID to ensure that the job starts exactly one time.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs#generate-jobid